# Adding a progress bar to lme4 (g)lmer() model computation

Tags: r, lme4

**Is there a way / workaround to add a progress bar (of any sort) for a `lmer()` model computation?**

I often find myself waiting couple of hours for a model and would use some sort of indication how long this might take in order to plan CPU workloads efficiently.

Comment: If computation time is proportional to imput size I prefer to run function on 1% (or any small subset on data) and estimate how long it will take.

Comment: My gut says that with `lmer()` and a complicated random structure running time for a 1% subset not necessarily will be proportional

Comment: So do a 1%, 2%, 5%, 10% sample until you get a handle on how long a 100% sample will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no progress bar. You might want to suggest this in the issue tracker:

```
URL: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/ http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/
BugReports: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues
```

or email the maintainer:

```
Maintainer: Ben Bolker <bbolker+lme4@gmail.com>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do as you propose and mark it answered as long as something changes